# Unix shell script to find a file and replace name by pattern

Tags: shell, unix

I have a folder called `/input/temp`. Inside the folder I have lot of files. I need to find the file of pattern `Article_????_test_?????????.txt` and replace by format below.

```
Article_????_?????????.txt
```

Below is the code I tried and which doesn't work:

```
echo "Please provide the file name Corresponding to DC..."
read file 
ls $HOME/*.txt | grep $file
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
find . $file '*_Test_*' -exec bash -c 'mv $0 ${0/_Test/ }' {} \;

    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
find . $file -name "*.txt" -exec bash -c "mv {} \`echo {} | sed -e 's/[_TEST_]/_/g'\`" \;
then
```

I Got below error:

```
find: 0652-083 Cannot execute bash:: A file or directory in the path name does not exist.
find: 0652-083 Cannot execute bash:: A file or directory in the path name does not exist.
```

bash can't be executed on my platform.

Comment: What shell are you using then? What system is it?

Answer (score 1):

- Unless the file name is a regular expression you can use `if [ -e "$file" ]` instead of [`ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) + `grep` + `test`.
- When you do `find . $file '*_Test_*'` the last three parameters are actually taken as files or directories to search underneath! It will return

  - all files in the current directory,
  - all files in the directory `$file` *or* the path `$file` if it's not a directory, *and*
  - all files in any directories matching `*_Test_*` *or* their paths if they are not directories.
- There's no need for `bash` - you can run `mv` directly in `-exec`. This is just extra complexity for no gain.
- Use [`$(command)`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution) instead of `command` for much easier quote handling. Each `$()` has a separate quoting context, so you can do for example `echo "$(command "$(c2 "argument with spaces")")"`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the link [here](http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/search/label/rename):
This should work

```
ls -1 Article_????test?????????.txt|awk '{old=$0;gsub(/test/,"_",$0);system("mv \""old"\" "$0)}'
```

Comment: [You should not parse `ls` output like this.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: The page linked above explains it.

Answer (score 0):

Also try the 'rename' command.

```
rename 's/_test_/_/' *.txt
```

You can fine tune the regular expression...

Answer (score 0):

Update from your code:

```
cd $HOME
find . -name '*_Test_*' |while read line
do
  echo mv ${line) ${line/_Test/}
done
```

If you need search the pattern Article_????*test*?????????.txt, try this

```
cd $HOME
find . -name 'Article_????_test_?????????.txt' |while read line
do
  echo mv ${line) ${line/_Test/}
done
```